# How to use fortran's spread function to copy an array block-wise instead of column-wise?

Tags: fortran

For example, this code:

```
program sandbox
    implicit none
    real, dimension(2, 2) :: p
    p = reshape((/ 1, 3, 2, 4 /), shape(p))

    print *, spread(P, 2, 2)

end program sandbox
```

returns this array:

```
1 1 2 2
3 3 4 4
```

but I'm trying to get it to return this"

```
1 2 1 2
3 4 3 4
```

Is this possible using `spread`? In actuality, it needs to be generalized, because I may be producing matrices like

```
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4
```

depending on other variables that I won't know at compile time.

Comment: My output is `1 3 1 3 2 4 2 4` and is really a 2x2x2 array, not a 2x4 array.

Comment: Yeah, that's what mine outputs, but I didn't notice that it's not a 2x4 array so I just typed it up how I thought it was. Is there an easy way to just print the total dimensions of an array, instead of printing `size(p, 1)`, `size(p, 2)`, etc. all separately.

Comment: I removed my previous, completely dumb comment: there is obviously a function that give you dimensions, and we both used it recently: `shape(p)`   ! :-)

Comment: @arbautjc I should have just looked that up because that's *exactly* what I was looking for. Ok, RTFM in more detail next time.

Comment: @arbautjc (Oops, can't edit the comment, but just to be sure, the RTFM is directed at me, not you. Thanks for the help!)

Comment: No hurt :-) Actually, I didn't find it in the F90 Handbook at first, then I asked myself: where would it be useful? ... D'oh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (all is in the Fortran 90 standard except the `[ ]` notation in place of `(/ /)`)

```
program sandbox
   implicit none
   real, dimension(2, 2) :: p
   real, dimension(2, 4) :: q
   integer i

   print *, "p"
   p = reshape([1, 3, 2, 4], shape(p))
   do i=1, 2
      print *, p(i, :)
   end do

   print *, "spread (orig)"
   q = reshape(spread(p, 2, 2), [2, 4])
   do i=1, 2
      print *, q(i, :)
   end do

   print *, "spread"
   q = reshape(spread(transpose(p), 2, 2), [2, 4], order=[2, 1])
   do i=1, 2
      print *, q(i, :)
   end do

   print *, "[p, p]"
   q = reshape([p, p], [2, 4])
   do i=1, 2
      print *, q(i, :)
   end do
end program sandbox
```

Comment: Awesome, I went with #3 ("spread") because it easy to generalize it to more copies of `p`. My final code looks like [this (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/9SZwSnL0).